# Robust pattern recognition algorithm

Tags: pattern-recognition

Imagine, you have 100-1000 images that look like the following

[image]

What is the best algorithm to identify this pattern uniquely, even if it's rotated

[image]

or zoomed

[image]

or even shifted and/or partly cropped?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to solve here is Cluster identification problem. The 100-1000 images you describe in your question are all large cluster of unlabeled dataset. There exist multiple Cluster Identification algorithms which will be perfect in your case such as **k-means algorithm, k-modes algorithm or k-Nearest Neighbor algorithm**.

Basically how data clustering works is that they statistically categorize similar clusters based on multiple similarity features like the cluster's size, density, distance, shape, etc. into classes such that there forms a group of similar and dissimilar clusters. Using the clustering algorithm your machine can learn to recognize patterns by observing as many dataset you intend to feed it.

Now, when you zoom the image or rotate/crop the image you just increase the noise in your dataset. Noises makes the data clustering process more tedious but it is doable. You can refer to this [paper](http://www.idc-online.com/technical_references/pdfs/information_technology/Pattern%20Recognition.pdf) if you want to learn more about data clustering algorithms.